# Find the Sum and the open interval of convergence of $\frac{(n+4)x^{n+2}}{n!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, power-series

Question regarding how to find the sum of the series and interval of convergence for $$\displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{(n+4)x^{n+2}}{n!}$$ find the interval of Convergence

I have found the interval of Convergence to Be R =

I am wonder how would the sum of this series be found

Comment: the term in the title of the question is different from the one in the question. which one is correct ? And please use LateX notation

Comment: It is n+4 NOT n+1 sorry about this

Answer (score 1):

$$S=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty }\frac{nx^{n+2}}{n!}+4\sum_{n=2}^{\infty }\frac{x^{n+2}}{n!}$$
$$S=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty }\frac{x^{n+2}}{(n-1)!}+4x^2\sum_{n=2}^{\infty }\frac{x^n}{n!}$$
$$S=x^3\sum_{n=2}^{\infty }\frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}+4x^2\sum_{n=2}^{\infty }\frac{x^n}{n!}$$

we know that 
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{x^n}{n!}=e^x$$
so
$$S=x^3(e^x-1)+4x^2(e^x-1-x)$$

Comment: also @DragonDude be careful that your series starts from 2 and not from 0 like $e^x$ so you should substract the first two terms

Comment: @DragonDude you r welcome

Answer (score 0):

∑(((n+4)xⁿ⁺²)/(n!))=x³∑((xⁿ⁻¹)/((n-1)!))+4x²∑((xⁿ)/(n!))=(x³+4x²)e^{x}